# PDF not open in window on primrose server browser "Fail to load PDF"

Tags: c#, wcf, pdf, server, iis-8

Server: Windows 2012 R2
IIS: 8.5 version
I have a WCF service application published in IIS.
The application has a PDF directory and tried to open PDF using the server URL.
For example https://example.com/WCF/PDFdirectory/filename.pdf
then some of the time gets an "**fail to load PDF document**" error

whereas I tried to open in locally using localhost then I never get this error.
For example http://localhost:8081/WCF/PDFdirectory/filename.pdf

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Clearing browser history and cache and then tried to open PDF and tried many things to resolve this error so I am expecting to properly resolve this error on server

Comment: Hi, I have some questions to ask. What browser are you using? Do you have the same problem with other browsers? And is this error bound to appear every time?

Comment: Yes, i got this error in every browser and  this error comes with intermittent behaviour,

Comment: I saw this thread, the problem is similar to what you describe, maybe it will help you. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5742